# How to return a location as x,y,z

Tags: c++, return, accessor

How can I make this return x and y, instead of just one of them? 
In my Location class, I have protected data named `x_pos` and `y_pos`.

```
void Location::getXY(double& x, double& y) const {
    x_pos = x;
    y_pos = y;
    return x, y;
}
```

Comment: Would a std::pair or std::tuple do? Else just can the references be in and out variables?

Comment: Return a `std::pair`? Return a `std::tuple`? Return a `std::array`? Return a `std::vector`? Return a structure?

Comment: Or, since you pass `x` and `y` as non-constant references, just assign to them?

Comment: Why do you need to return unaltered the very parameters you just passed ?

Comment: If you "have protected data named x_pos and y_pos", then I would expect a method named `getXY()` to return them, and not set their value, like your `getXY()` does. You seem to be doing something backwards.

Comment: Why return what was passed to the function in the first place? Are you sure you don't have the assignments backwards (in which case a return is not necessary, since they are references)?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a `std::pair`. I am assuming you want to return by value and not by reference here.

```
#include <utility> // for std::pair 

// if using c++14, else use std::pair<double,double> as return type 
auto Location::getXY(double& x, double& y) const {
    x_pos = x;
    y_pos = y;
    return std::make_pair(x,y);
}
```

Although i must note that this function doesn't make logical sense, you are returning values which you passed to begin with without modifying them.

Comment: You don't actually need `decltype(auto)` here, `auto` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably meant

```
void Location::getXY(double& x, double& y) const {
    x = x_pos;
    y = y_pos;
}
```

This way you store `Location`'s internal `x_pos` and `y_pos` in provided locations. You don't need to `return` anything from a function returning `void` (actually, you cannot return anything but `void` itself).
As everyone said before, returning an `std::pair` might be a better idea.